# Selenium, Python, is it possible to narrow down a locator?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm wondering whether it makes any difference in narrowing down locators and also whether it is more efficient to do so, because the query is not being made several times to find the div?

For instance, is it possible to do a find_element_by_id on the parent div tag, and save that as a variable. Then use that variable to call find_element_by_xpath (thereby shortening all the xpath queries?

e.g.

```
d = find_element_by_id('myid')
e = d.find_element_by_xpath('//img')
```

Which would get the img tag inside of myid div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you should specify that you need to start searching not from the root `html` element

```
e = d.find_element_by_xpath('//img')
```

but from parent element which is `d` in your case:

```
e = d.find_element_by_xpath('.//img')
```

Note the dot `.` before `//`

Comment: ahaa, lovely thanks Andersson :). I'm guessing it's also possible to run a for loop on the div tag, so get  all the img tags inside multiple divs?

Comment: Yes it also possible to get all images for each `div` in this way